# How to filter out an "API Only" user using an SOQL Query?

Tags: apex, soql, permissions, user

I am trying to create  an SOQL Query to filter out "**API Only**" users from List of Users.

However, I am not able to find the field in which this value will be there. I found a solution [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000003819&language=en_US) but could not find the field "**PermissionsApiUserOnly**" neither from Profile object or from User object.

I tried to find the above mentioned field using API Version 29.0 and 24.0, but was not able to find this field on neither the User object nor Profile Object. It seems that the above mentioned field has been deprecated.

I was able to find **PermissionsApiEnabled** on Profile but it just tells that the API is enabled for this User or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me with API 29 :

```
System.debug('>>>'+[select u.FirstName, u.Profile.PermissionsApiUserOnly From User u]);
```

Comment: For me, it is giving this error for API 29.0 :

COMPILE ERROR: No such column 'PermissionsApiUserOnly' on entity 'Profile'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
LINE: 1 COLUMN: 20